# WiFi Direct - only one device (Samsung phone)

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, file-transfer, data-transfer, wifi-direct

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct):

> Only one of the Wi-Fi devices needs to be compliant with Wi-Fi Direct to establish a peer-to-peer connection that transfers data directly between them with greatly reduced setup.

How to actually establish the Wifi Direct connection from one Samsung Android phone (with Wifi Direct enabled) with another Samsung Android phone (**without** Wifi Direct / with Wifi Direct **disabled**)?

(FYI, I could establish connection with Wifi Direct enabled on both phones. But theoretically only enabling one phone is enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the app [SuperBeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam) to receive files on a device without wifi direct from one that does have it.

Comment: I found there are ways from the Internet. But theoretically Wifi Direct still works when only one device has it, natively without another app, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, for how the standard is defined it should be possible.